# Parameters usage in DAX Formula

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have created a parameter which has values 1-20.

Now I want to use this in a calculated column , wherein the calculations is

```
if(Parameter[Parameter Value]>'GPH Activity'[Idle Time 2],1,0)
```

Here Idle time is a number field.

This however doesn't seem to work. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use parameters in `Calculated Columns`, only in `Measures`.

Calculated Columns are calculated when the data model is refreshed, they're not dynamically recalculated as the report is consumed.

Decide how you wish to aggregate this calculation, and write an appropriate measure instead. You may wish to use an `Iterator` function, such as `COUNTX` or `SUMX`.